# User name troubles on windows/linux network

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10

We run a server for 60 employees on 60 pc's, and counting my personal computers, that becomes about 65.

The server runs ubuntu 15.04.02 (Don't know about the .02, but it shouldn't matter) and all the computers run Windows 7 Premium/Ultimate. Until now.

I installed Windows 10 onto my main computer, and now I cannot get the username to BE anything. It just stays "other user". I tried the method brought up [here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiH8IOIi7jJAhVDWhQKHe7pCLQQFggqMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thewindowsclub.com%2Fchange-account-username-in-windows-10-when-signed-in-using-microsoft-account&usg=AFQjCNEteCUc7X0KtoPzR6CNgio_5DU43g&sig2=xJsgSg8x-LOPphsjyFlu4A&bvm=bv.108194040,d.ZWU) but to no avail. Can anyone help, or at least point me the right way

Comment: You may want to add a bit more detail here: Is the server running Samba in AD controller mode? Is there some other AD involved?  What 'it' just says 'other user'? The login screen?

Comment: @MrMajestyk, yes just the login screen. Give me a bit to work out the AD, i kinda forgot it :)